# Azure durable function log stream showing deleted function

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

I have deployed a change to a durable function product into Azure DevOps and part of the work was to rename an activity function.

However the warning below is appearing in the log stream containing the *old* name for the function.

> [Warning] Activity function 'PublishNotification' does not exist..
> InstanceId: . Function: PublishNotification.

[image]

This function publishes a message to a Service bus topic, and there is definitely now no reference to that function name anywhere in the code.

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the Azure web job storage queues and had a look around. Turns our there was an old message (about 4 days old) stuck in one of the queues and when that was cleared out the warning messages disappeared too.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that your function name has been changed, the orchestrator function listener and other function listeners are been deregistered:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/f6f1dce716b68d8baaa99ed64a9db1306577c58d/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/Listener/DurableTaskListener.cs#L44-L54

But the orchestrator function is still running, and it cannot find your previous function name:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/f6f1dce716b68d8baaa99ed64a9db1306577c58d/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableOrchestrationContext.cs#L385

If you restart the function app and let everything start again, can you still reproduce this error?

Comment: I've done this and it's made no difference